# how to select the n'th charachter of a string

Tags: php

i have a string like below:

```
2021-08-03-1
```

i just want to select the `1` at the end of the string . how can i do that ?? i already tried `str_split`

```
$ids = str_split($date['id'],1);
```

and i have tried this :

```
$ids = str_split($date['id'],1);
```

but the result was like below :

```
array:12 [
  0 => "2"
  1 => "0"
  2 => "2"
  3 => "1"
  4 => "-"
  5 => "0"
  6 => "8"
  7 => "-"
  8 => "0"
  9 => "3"
  10 => "-"
  11 => "1"
]
```

but it gives me an array full of all charachters i wanted to know if there is an easier way doing it , thanks

Comment: `substr($date['id'] -1);` will return `1`, it will select the last character of a given string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel `last()` [helper function](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-last) as below:

```
last(str_split('2021-08-03-1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

try to fetch last element of array it will return ur expected output . for that u can use end () or array_slice($a,-1) both will return the last element

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
end(explode('-','2021-08-03-1'))


$str = '2021-08-03-1';
$arr = explode('-',$str); // explode() will convert string to array
$record = end($arr); // end() will give you last element of array
```